# how to upload an image to the firebase with specific user only in reactnative?

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, react-redux

I'm building an app as my homework and stuck in a problem i am not understnding that how to add image of a specific user and then display after login?

Comment: Please could you provide more informations about the process ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Storage to upload your images from mobile device or backend.

You would need to signup for [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) for this.

if you want to directly upload from device, you can use REST API like this:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT_LOCATION] \
-H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
-H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
"https://www.googleapis.com.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs)